# .split() doesn't transform string in list

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup

in my code i'm trying to split a string and put links(that are in the string ) in an array, with the method .split(), but when i try to do that.

```
ciao = []
for article in soup.find_all("a", {"style": "height:81px;"}):
    ciao = article.get("href").split()
    print(ciao[1])
```

i get the error : "IndexError: list index out of range

so i tryed to print out the list

```
ciao = []
for article in soup.find_all("a", {"style": "height:81px;"}):
    ciao = article.get("href").split()
    print (ciao)
```

it gives me:

```
[link1]
[link2]
[link3]
[link4]
[link5]
[link6]
...
```

instead of

```
[link1, link2, link3, ...]
```

can you explain me why and how can i correct my code to obtain a list?

Comment: Why are you trying to call `split`? Does `get("href")` not already give you a link as a string? So what good does splitting it do? Just append the links to a list as you "get" them, and that'll be your "list".

Comment: print (article.get("href")) give me : link1 link2 link3 ...

Comment: No. `ciao.append(article.get('href'))`

Comment: if i do that, it gives me :

if i print (ciao[1]): list out of index

if i print (ciao) : multiple lists like : first with [link1] , second with [link1, link2] and so on

Comment: No one asked you to print anything inside the loop. Just append it, won't you?

Comment: oh now i understood what i did and i feel so retarded ahah , thanks all for answers , i fixed it with .append(), i only tought .find_all() returns all tags in a string, but then i shouldn't have done a for loop, thanks <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to extract a tags from your page this is enough

```
a_nodes = soup.find_all("a", {"style": "height:81px;"})
hrefs = [a_node.get('href') for a_node in a_nodes] # and this extracts hrefs from those
```

Your code does not split because you are trying to split a single url and that has no spaces in it (and it's not what you want as well, I suppose).

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning link to list and printing in each iteration, in each iteration you assign you will overwrite previous list.

Instead you can append the links to list and then print it to your get desire result as below:

```
ciao = []
for article in soup.find_all("a", {"style": "height:81px;"}):
    if article.has_attr("href"):  # this if condition is not necessary but I recommand it while scraping so if a tag without href attribute won't throw an exception
        ciao.append(article.get("href"))
print (ciao)
```

If you don't want to use the list in future and just print the link you can just use print function with `end=', '` like `print(article.get("href"))` in for loop.

A one liner with list comprehension:

```
ciao=[article.get("href") for article in soup.find_all("a", {"style": "height:81px;"}) if article.has_attr("href")]
```

Comment: Don't split it, (you don't need to)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I didn't changed that code because it doesn't mention in question what it does--- updated as seen in comment

Comment: OP is trying to scrape href links from some website, using beautifulsoup. `get` will return the string in the href attribute for that tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic is unclear for you:

```
soup.find_all("a", {"style": "height:81px;"})
```

This retrieves a list of articles, so

```
ciao = article.get("href")
```

will return a **single** link for the article. To get the list of links there are a few options, one is the famous list comprehension:

```
mylist = [article.get('href') for article in soup.find_all("a", {"style": "height:81px;"})]
```

and you might also like to be acquainted with `map`, which is considered a bit more 'complex', especially since I'm involving a `lambda` term:

```
mylist = list(map(lambda article: article.get('href'),soup.find_all("a", {"style": "height:81px;"})))
```

If you want to iterate the list you can leave it as a map. The logic in both solutions is you want to convert `soup.find_all` list by applying to each item a `get`.

Comment: You're complicating things unnecessarily, change the `map` to something better for an upvote...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ How can I refuse that offer? I left the `map` in case OP wants to peek ahead, if you think that's productive.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Merry Christmas to all!

Answer (score 1):

There are three errors here:

1. You are calling `print(ciao[1])`, when in Python lists are indexed from 0. This means to get the first item in the list you would call `print(ciao[0])`, or to get the whole list you would call only `print(ciao)`
2. You aren't adding to the list, you are resetting it. To do this, you use `list.append(item)`.
3. You (in most cases) dont want to split a link, and there is no need to do that in this implementation. (from what I can see, anyways)

Fixing these errors you get the new code:

```
ciao = []
for article in soup.find_all("a", {"style": "height:81px;"}):
    ciao.append(article.get("href"))
print (ciao)
```